# Placing a cookie to cookies collection according to a checkbox's Checked property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `Checkbox` that places a cookie when `Checked`. The cookie stores the value "Like" when the `Checkbox` is checked and the value "Dislike" when the checkbox is unchecked. However, checking the checkbox stores the value "Like" but unchecking it Doesn't store "Dislike", that is because the page load should set the checkbox to `true` when the value in the cookie is "Like" and to `false` when the value is "Dislike".

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string coursename = Request.QueryString["coursename"].ToString();
        HttpCookie recivedCookie = Request.Cookies[User.Identity.Name + coursename + "LikeCookie"];
        if (Request.Cookies[User.Identity.Name + coursename + "LikeCookie"] != null)
        {
            if (recivedCookie.Values["UserLike"] == "Like")
            {
                LikeCheckBox.Checked = true;
            }
            else if (recivedCookie.Values["UserLike"] == "Dislike")
            {
                LikeCheckBox.Checked = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Cookie is null");
        }
    }
//===================================================
    protected void LikeCheckBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string coursename = Request.QueryString["coursename"].ToString();
        CheckBox thisCheckBox = sender as CheckBox;
        Request.Cookies.Remove(User.Identity.Name + coursename + "LikeCookie");   // To remove the old cookie and create a new cookie whenever the checkbox's index changed
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(User.Identity.Name + coursename + "LikeCookie");
        cookie.Expires.AddDays(10);
        if (cookie.Values["UserLike"] == null)
        {
            if (thisCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                cookie.Values.Add("UserLike", "Like");
            }
            else
            {
                cookie.Values.Add("UserLike", "Dislike");
            }
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're wiring up the wrong event... `SelectedIndexChanged` is usually for lists/tables and has nothing to do with the content being checked/unchecked

Comment: Please use OnCheckedChanged event rather than SelectedIndexChanged because you are trying to capture check changed on a checkbox.

Comment: This line `if (cookie.Values["UserLike"] == null` will always be false, because you just created the cookie.

Comment: To remove a cookie, don't remove it from the Request.  This has no effect on the browser's cookie jar.  Instead, add a new cookie to the response.  That's all you have to do.  To completely remove the cookie, set the expiration date of the cookie in the past.

Comment: @JohnWu 
what edit to do in the code above to do so? I deleted the line : Request.Cookies.Remove(User.Identity.Name + coursename + "LikeCookie"); but it didn't work